# Huawei E3372 Hi-Link doesn't work with macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, lte

Since Catalina dropped 32-bit support my LTE router, Huawei E3372 Hi-Link, stopped working. Is there any 64-bit driver(?) available to make the device work again?

Before, after plugging in the stick an Apple Script was auto-run and router admin interface located at http://192.168.8.1 was opened automatically.

Now the Volume called HiLink is mounted but the app cannot be started since it's 32-bit.

The [solutions to make Huawei work with Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338572/lte-usb-dongle-huawei-datacard-driver-on-macos-mojave) don’t work for me.

Where can I find a workaround app or update?

Comment: The actual link is https://consumer-tkb.huawei.com/weknow/servlet/download/public?contextNo=S1601327038. It is tested with Big Sur. You could find it on huawei.com in Support-Customer Support:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvKmG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvKmG.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Huawei has posted an update for mobile sticks drivers for Hilink products you can use [this](https://consumer-tkb.huawei.com/tkbapp/downloadWebsiteService?websiteId=1697201).

For the other devices (that use mobile partner or mobile WiFi): visit [this link](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/routers/e3372/) and then click software section; you'll find the driver for your device.

Answer (score 2):

I flashed my Huawei e3372h-153 with Stick firmware and I'm able to connect via modem in Catalina.
Instructions [here](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=582284&st=20#entry39517088).
The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of macOS. Contact the developer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Huawei WIFI mini 2 (which is different than yours) and I contacted their customer services, they responded very quickly and sent me a new driver by email within 1 day. Now my problem is solved and they told me that they will release new drivers very soon.

I am assuming Huawei is working on a driver for your device too.